# How can I align my element with the div below it?

Tags: css, css-grid

Using `grid` I have a row of six div elements. If you notice just above the far right div there is an `a` element that says *"View All"*. I have that div (and the `p` tag) wrapped in a div and I'm using `justify-content: space-between` so they appear on opposite ends however the *"View All"* is not perfectly aligned with the div below it and is a few pixels to the right. I have all of the elements wrapped in a main div with `max-width: 1220px` but for some reason they still aren't perfectly aligned.

I'm trying to figure out why that is. I have no margin or padding in the `box` div so I don't know what I've done wrong. This isn't too noticeable in a larger screen but when I make my browser smaller you can notice a difference.

What I'm asking is what can I do to make the *"View All"* `a` tag be perfectly aligned with the div below it, even in smaller screens.

```css
.main {
    max-width: 1220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

.popular {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(185px, 1fr));
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 265px;
    width: 185px;
}

.view {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 4em;
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="view">
        <p>Popular</p>
        <a href="/search/popular">View All</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popular">
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `minmax()` with `1fr`. Define only the width of your div to make sure the column will all have a fixed size then use the same justify-content as the flexbox container

```css
.main {
    max-width: 1220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

.popular {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 185px);
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 265px;
}

.view {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 4em;
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="view">
        <p>Popular</p>
        <a href="/search/popular">View All</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popular">
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
        <div id="manga" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```